# Run a single command NOT through my VPN, with all other traffic through my VPN

Tags: networking, vpn

I'd like to use my VPN for all network traffic *except* for the traffic from a single, arbitrary command. Is there a way to do this?

I understand there may be easier ways to do roughly what I want; for example, if my command were ssh, I could set up routing so that outgoing connections to port 22 don't go through the VPN. This has the limitation, though, that I have to know the ports my command uses, and that if I ran another ssh session at the same time, it would also not go through the VPN; I just want the one command to do that. I'd also like for this to work regardless of what ports the command uses or what addresses it connects to (which I haven't so far been able to find an example of anywhere).

Thanks!

Comment: It would probably help to know what command you are using.  As of now I'm thinking you could setup a script that will grab the IP you are trying to execute the command against, create a temporary route for that IP that bypasses your vpn, executes the command, and then remove the route.

Answer (score 0):

One way to run commands which are routed differently is to use iptables and policy routing. You can create a new user (or group) which you use to run the command.

Mark the traffic in `mangle` table using iptables owner module. In this example traffic is marked with identification *10* for user *novpn*:

```
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid novpn -j MARK --set-mark 10
```

Create a new routing table (table *100*) for marked traffic and set a default route and rule to apply the new routing table for marked traffic:

```
ip route add table 100 default via *DEFAULTGW*
ip rule add fwmark 10 table 100
ip route flush cache
```

Now to run command which isn't routed via your VPN you can use `su` etc. to run the command as the new novpn user.

If creating a new user to run commands as is not acceptable, you could set up a separate [network namespace](https://lwn.net/Articles/580893/) with its own routing to run your commands in.

Comment: Thanks! I tried this, but I end up completely unable to connect to the internet as novpn when my VPN is active. Any idea why?
 https://pastebin.com/tRM5w7e2

Comment: Did you verify your traffic gets marked in mangle table (check counters using `iptables -L -v -t mangle`)? Can you reach your gateway as `vpn` user, if you can can you ping hosts in internet (using IP address instead of DNS name)? Does your VPN alter DNS configuration?

Comment: I just checked, it does get marked. My VPN does alter DNS config, but it's not just a DNS resolution issue; `ping` as `novpn` can't reach plain IP addresses either (nor can `wget` etc). As `novpn` I can ping my gateway though.